# How to Illustrator Apply a value and keep focus in edit field

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

Shift + Enter

Apply a value and keep focus in edit field

Comment: welcome to GD.SE! Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add some more detail / format it properly (Punctuation, actual complete sentences, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain what you are intending to ask. A little more information in the question certainly wouldn't hurt.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> has no direct function in Illustrator's Transform Panel. 
At least not in any version I'm running here.

What I do....

- Enter value
- Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again

The <kbd>Tab</kbd> will commit the value and move the *the next field in the panel*. Then the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Tab moves back to the *previous field in the panel*.

By repeating this process, it essentially allows one to continually alter a value in a panel field *without* any need for a "click" anywhere.